# Why does F# allow attributes that don't inherit from System.Attribute?

Tags: f#

I created an F# 'Nunit' project using a template in VS 2019 to do some testing, and the default fixture code it created was the following:

```ml
namespace Tests

open NUnit.Framework

[<TestClass>]
type TestClass () =

    [<SetUp>]
    member this.Setup () =
        ()

    [<Test>]
    member this.Test1 () =
        Assert.Pass()
```

It's an otherwise ordinary looking class, except the curiosity on the class declaration. I expected to see `[<TestFixture>]`, but instead I see `[<TestClass>]`, the same name as the auto-generated type. I suspect that this is a bug in the project template, but strangely, F# will happily compile this, with a note that it probably won't be compatible with other .Net languages:

`warning FS3242: This type does not inherit Attribute, it will not work correctly with other .NET languages.`

crystal clear for me. My question is, why does F# even allow this? Do the reflection capabilities in .Net even work for such an attribute in F#? What would a potential use-case be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Historically the check was forgotten to be added to the compiler. When it was discovered, I propose to make it compilation error, but it ended up as a warning for backward compatible reasons. See https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/pull/5192 and https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/pull/5610 for details.

Answer (score 1):

Alas, I do not have the answer to the question why F# allows this. A quick experimentation shows that using ordinary classes as attributes works - at least in a very basic situation:

```
type A(n:int) = 
  member x.N = n

[<A(10)>]
type B() = class end

(typeof<B>.GetCustomAttributes(true).[1] :?> A).N
```